# ¿Cómo agregar un código de retorno para saber en mi front (Angular) que todo es Ok o que sucedio algun error?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, angular11

Tengo el siguiente servicio Java que consulta a una base de datos Oracle y me regresa una lista la cual yo muestro finalmente en mi frontend con Angular, mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo agregar algún código de retorno o un Success en mi codigo Java para poder validar en mi frontend y que yo pueda mostrar un mensaje si es que algo fallo al consultar en la base o que no se encuentren datos con las fechas enviadas? , es decir, si por alguna razon la BD no esta disponible solo se visualizara en mi log de Java, pero como lo muestro en Angular a traves de un mensaje en pantalla

Servicio Java

```html
@CrossOrigin(origins ="http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
    @RestController
    public class ConsultarValoresController {
        
        @Autowired
        private ConsultarValoresService  consultarValoresService  

        @GetMapping()
        public List<ValoresDTO> listar(@RequestParam (required=false, value="fechaInicio") Integer fechaInicio, 
        @RequestParam (required=false, value="fechaFin") Integer fechaFin) throws Exception{
            List<ValoresDTO> listaValores = new ArrayList<ValoresDTO>();
        try {
            listaValores = consultarValoresService.consultarValores(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in  Values ");
            throw e;
        }
        return listaValores;
    }
```

```html
@Service
    public class ConsultarValoresServiceImpl implements ConsultarValoresService{
        @Autowired
        private ConsultarValoresRepository consultarValoresRepository 
        
        @Override
        public List<ValoresDTO> consultarValores(Integer fechaInicio, Integer fechaFin) {
        try {
            Integer ini = fechaInicio;
            Integer fin = fechaFin;
            return consultarValoresRepository.consultarValoresBd(ini, fin);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for Data");
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

```html
 public interface ConsultarValoresRepository  extends JpaRepository<ValoresDto, Integer>{                
        @Query(value="select * from TABLE_VALORES t where t.fechaRegistro between ?1 and ?2", nativeQuery =true)
        List<ValoresDto> consultarValoresBd(Integer fechInicio, Integer fechaFin);
    }
```

Angular

Component.ts

```html
consultarDatos() {
    if (this.valoresForm.valid) {
        this.service.consultarValores(this.inicioFech, this.finFech).subscribe(data=>{
          this.modelConsultarValores=data;
        })
      

    } else {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        text: 'Debes seleccionar ambas fechas'
      })
    }
  }
```

Service.ts

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {ValoresDto} from '../Models/ValoresDTO';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConsultarValoresService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  Url = 'http://localhost:8080/consultarValores';

  
  consultarValores(fechaInicio:any, fechaFin:any){
    return this.http.get<ValoresDTO[]>(this.Url+ `?fechaInicio=${fechaInicio}&fechaFin=${fechaFin}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dice la documentación de RxJS, el método [subscribe](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable#subscribe-) recibe como parámetro un [Observer](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/Observer). Un observer es una interfaz que tiene 3 métodos `next`, `error` y `complete`.

En el ejemplo solamente se está pasando `next` que se ejecuta cuando llega el siguiente valor del observable. En caso de haber un error es la función `error` la que sería ejecutada, por lo que es el mejor lugar para hacer lo que tradicionalmente haría un catch. Y `complete` se ejecuta cuando el observable es completado, es decir que ya no va a recibir más valores.

En este caso podría quedar algo así:

```
consultarDatos() {
  if (this.valoresForm.valid) {
    this.service.consultarValores(this.inicioFech, this.finFech).subscribe({
     next: data => {
      this.modelConsultarValores=data;
     },
     error: (err) => console.error(err),
     complete: () => console.log('Consulta completada')
   });
  } else {
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'error',
      text: 'Debes seleccionar ambas fechas'
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola, una duda o sea que si en mi servicio java la lista regresa vacia de que no hay datos con ese rango de fechas, en el front con este codigo que agregaste caeria en el error?

Comment: No, quedaría en `next`, error solamente se da si la petición HTTP tiene un error.

Comment: y si quisiera agregar esa validación para mostrar al usuario que no hay nada en esas fechas?

Comment: si en error => en lugar de poner el console quiero poner un mensaje con Swal como seria?